# Range simplification

Tags: python

```
list1 = [6,1,3]
for item in list1:
  result = ""
  for y in range(item):
    result += "*"
  print(result)
```

This will output in the console:

```
******

*

***
```

The question if it's possible to have a simpler code (simplify) to make this done ? I'm new here and new to python so really sorry if thats not a hard question, thank you for understanding

and please do not say:

```
print("******\n*\n***")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print('\n'.join('*'*i for i in (6,1,3)))
```

Comment: Well, that looks simple but still not for my level :)) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sure
you can have

```
for i in list1:
    print(i*'*')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can repeat a string a specified number of times using the `*` operator. So:

```
"Python" * 3
```

or

```
3 * "Python"
```

gives:

```
"PythonPythonPython"
```

You could write a function to generate the pattern:

```
def generate_pattern(frequencies, pattern = '*'):
    lines = (pattern * i for i in frequencies)
    return lines
```

Or:

```
def generate_pattern(frequencies, pattern = '*'):    
    return map(lambda f: f * pattern, frequencies)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
lines = generate_pattern([6, 1, 3])
```

```
print(*lines, sep="\n")
```

or

```
for line in generate_pattern([6, 1, 3]):
    print(line)
```

You can also pass in a custom string:

```
lines = generate_pattern([6, 1, 3], pattern="#")
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional programming approach: termwise multiplication the pattern by the values given in the list and concatenate everything with a newline separator.

```
list1 = [6,1,3]

star = '*'
out = '\n'.join(map(star.__mul__, list1))
print(out)
```

or, just for fun, with [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
from functools import reduce

list1 = [6,1,3]

star = '*'

out = reduce(lambda string, amount: f'{string}\n{star*amount}', list1, '')
print(out)
```

NOTE: string concatenation should be done with [*join*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), see doc point 6.